# downloading yearly data from PNADc with lodowm

Tags: r

Is it possible to download yearly data from PNADc using lodown?
I have tried this already:

```
pnadc_cat <- subset( pnadc_cat , year == 2015 & interview == '1' )
```

instead of

```
pnadc_cat <- subset( pnadc_cat , year == 2015 & quarter == '03' )
```

but it didn't work.

And I didn't see any references regarding data per year in the lodown's tips.
I guess it is because it only downloads the quartely data...but is it possible other way around?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only year == 2015 as the condition for your subset function. It will subset data for all quarter in 2015.

```
pnadc_cat2015 <- subset( pnadc_cat , year == 2015 )
```